# what would cause the second chime of a doorbell to sound muted?

Tags: doorbell

I've got a doorbell that works, it is the normal two chime "ding dong", but it goes "ding chunk" where the second chime seems muted.  I looked at it and it's mounted right, it gets hit with enough force.  What would cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that there was an intereference hitting into it--the cord coming into the doorbell box "from the wall" was bent up and barely touching the chime bar.  So bent it down a little and working doorbell again.

Comment: It's also common (though not the case here, it seems) to have a front/rear doorbell setup where one set of terminals goes "ding-dong" and the other just goes "ding."